# How do I block access to certain API resources on Apigee

Tags: apigee

I have an existing backend API with methods like:

(GET) /user/{id}

(GET) /user/delete/{id}

(GET) /user/create/firstName={firstName},lastName={lastName}

(yes, not exactly RESTful, since everything is a GET)

I want to configure my Apigee proxy to reject "/delete/" and "/create/" paths making my proxy read-only. I'm not sure whether to use some kind of conditional flow for this. How is it done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using the following steps:

1. Create three different resources in a proxy as:

   a. /user/{id} - GET
   b. /user/delete/{id} - GET
   c. /user/create/{abc}  - GET

Now, attach 'Raise Fault' policy to 'delete' and 'create' flows.

I hope that helps. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: That worked great! Thanks. What if I wanted some developers to access my create and delete resources and not others? Would it be better to just create a new "super" proxy to the same backend and just not have these Raise Fault policies on that version?

Comment: You should be able to do that. Another approach is basically to control the access using API Product, Developer and Developer apps. Please follow this document to get the basic understanding: http://apigee.com/docs/gateway-services/content/overview-1

Answer (score 1):

An alternate way of doing the same is using APIProducts.

1)Create an API product and add only a as the resource to the Product.
(a. /user/{id} - GET b. /user/delete/{id} - GET c. /user/create/{abc} - GET)

2)Attach your developer apikey to this product

3)When you do APIkey Validation automatically the developer will be allowed what is there in his APIProduct and nothing else.