# How to restrict APIGEE proxy to certain resources

Tags: apigee

I have Restful API with 40 endpoints like:

GET /user/:id
GET /users
POST /users

and etc....

I want to proxy API by Apigee but only certain endpoints, for example only one:

GET /users

Can't find the way how to do it.

When I add proxy it maps to all routes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I block access to certain API resources on Apigee](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054707/how-do-i-block-access-to-certain-api-resources-on-apigee)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Target API is at `http://hostname/basepath/`
Assuming that `GET /users` is equivalent to `GET http://hostname/basepath/users` and so on..
You'll need to create a API proxy with the Target URL: `http://hostname/basepath`
Then, inside the API proxy, you need to create a *resource* for each valid (permitted) verb + resource path.
For example, If `GET /users` and `GET /users/:id` is permitted, you need to create 2 resources in your API proxy:
`GET /users`
`GET /users/*`
This can be done from the UI at the *Overview* section in the API proxy.

Once you finished defining the allowed resources, you need to add a `Conditional Flow` with NO Condition, that only  responds with an Error (you can use a Raise Fault Policy). This can be done in the *Develop* section in the API proxy.
This Conditional Flow, MUST be at the end, so if the request does not match any of the resources, it will match this default Conditional Flow, and it will trigger your Raise Fault policy.